# Fetching private posts or custom post types via WP-API with basic authentication

Tags: custom-post-types, authentication, wp-api, private

I've installed [WP-API](http://wp-api.org) along with [Basic Auth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth). I'm able to fetch cpt posts using

```
curl http://siteurl.com/posts?type={post-type}
```

However, if I change a post to private, it is no longer returned. This is true even when sending the author's user credentials with either an auth header or simply using

```
curl http://username:password@siteurl.com/posts?type={post-type}
```

Is this by design? Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: Just want to specify, I'm looking for a way to get an author's private posts returned in the JSON feed while providing their credentials using Basic Auth.

Comment: Private posts are hidden from logged out users, this is by design and the purpose of private posts

Comment: Hi @PieterGoosen thanks for the response. I'm trying to get them to show up in the JSON feed for the author **while providing the author's credentials**

That shouldn't be treated as a _logged out user_ right?